# Multivariable birth and death process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, birth-death-process

I read about birth and death process in a paper. The paper then generalized the birth and death process as multivariable. The paper part is like in the picture : [image: Paper].
 Can anyone explain to me about this part? I totally don't understand. I understand about the one dimension birth and death process though.

Comment: Single variate would mean just one species birth and death, say humans. Multivariate means cats, dogs, mosquitos, etc. all happening simultaneously. The first term in summation is what happens when one one member of $j$'th species is born, second is for dead and third is excluding the intersection that we counted twice.

Comment: I understand about the general concept. What I don't understand is how this equation is derived. What is index j and k and what is E. The paper doesn't give explanation about the variable. Also, for one dimensional birth-date process, we can make picture of sequence of states and the direction of birth-date transistion rate. How to illustrate this multivariate?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\vec[1]{{\mathbf #1}}$
This is a general way to think about master equations: the rate of change of probability of the system being at a state $\vec k$ equals the rate at which the system transitions from some state $\vec l$ to the state $\vec k$ time the probability of the system being at that state $\vec l$ (summed over all such states $\vec l$) minus the probability of the system being already at the state $\vec k$ times the rate of the system transitioning out of $\vec k$ to some other state $\vec l$ (again summed over all such states $\vec l$):

$$\frac{dP(\vec k, t)}{dt} = \sum_{\vec l} T(\vec l\to \vec k)P(\vec l,t) - \sum_{\vec l} T(\vec k\to \vec l)P(\vec k,t), $$

where $T(\vec x\to\vec y)$ is the transition rate from the state $\vec x$ to the state $\vec y$.

In your case, the transitions are due to birth-death processes of $n$ different species. The $j$th birth process only allows the state $(k_1, \dots, k_j-1,\dots, k_n)\equiv \vec E_j^- \vec k$ to transition to the state $\vec k = (k_1, \dots,k_n)$. In your equation, the state dependent rate of this transition is given by $g_j$ which depends on the state that you transition from, that is  $\vec E_j^- \vec k$.

Similarly, the $j$th death process only allows the transitions of the state $(k_1, \dots, k_j+1,\dots, k_n)\equiv \vec E_j^+ \vec k$ to the state $\vec k$. The rate of this transition in your equation is given by $r_j(\vec E_j^+ \vec k)$.

Transitions out of the state $\vec k$ are due to $j$th birth process at the rate $g_j(\vec k)$ and $j$th death process at the rate $r_j(\vec k)$ for all $j=1,\dots,n$.

In summary, for the first term, $\sum_{\vec l} T(\vec l\to \vec k)P(\vec l,t)$, transition only from the states $\vec l = \vec E_j^\pm \vec k$ (for all $j$s) are allowed and have the rates $g_j(\vec E_j^- \vec k)$ and $r_j(\vec E_j^+ \vec k)$. This gives you the first two terms of your equation. And for the second term, transitions only to the states $\vec l = \vec E_j^\pm \vec k$ (for all $j$) are allowed, and they have the rates $g_j(\vec k)$ and $r_j(\vec k)$. This gives you the last term in your equation.

Comment: What I don't understand is the calculation of the matrix multiplication. First of all, what is the shape of matrix g and k. Can you give an example with just 2 species and some states? I am not a good mathematician so reading mathematical notation is a bit hard without clear explanation/example. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: $k$, $g$ and $r$ are all vectors of length $n$. $g(k)$ and $r(k)$ are functions of the state $k$ and do not have to be linear. Therefore, you cannot always express $g_j$s and $r_j$s as matrices.

Comment: $\renewcommand\vec[1]{{\mathbf #1}}$Here is an example. $\vec k = (k_1, k_2)$, where $k_1$ and $k_2$ can be numbers $0,1,2,\dots$. $\vec g(\vec k) = (g_1(\vec k), g_2(\vec k)) = (a\, k_1, b\, k_1\, k_2)$, and $\vec r(\vec k) = (r_1(\vec k), r_2(\vec k)) = (c, d\, k_2)$. Does this help?

Comment: So, g and r are vector with 2 rows and 1 column? How do I multiply it with the probability then?

Comment: I see where your confusion comes from. In this formula, the probability is given as a function of the state $\mathbf k$. For each $\mathbf k$ this formula holds. And for each $\mathbf k$ the probability is a number. Now, you are used to thinking of probability as a vector instead of a function. You can still do this, in this case, but it will get really complicated because your probability is now a function of all $k_1, \dots, k_n$, and it would be hard to index it. Just think of this applying element by element on each $\mathbf k$.

Comment: So, basically the calculation is similar with just one species birth-date process? I mean, for one species calculation, there is no other species effect in the calculation? The notation is just to shorten the writing instead of writing j number of equation?

Comment: The website is asking me to avoid extended discussion in comments, so here is my last comment: There is only one equation, not $j$ equations. The equation is for the joint probability of the system being at a state with $k_1$ of first species $k_2$ of second species and so on. The birth/death process from each species affects the rate of change of the joint probability, and hence the sum over $j$. In general, the birth/death rates of species depends on other species, like $g_2$ in the example above depending on both $k_1$ and $k_2$. Other than these everything else is the same.